# Different SMTP ports from Wifi to 3G

Tags: android

My android application uses the `JavaMail` library to send an email, with an attachment. Over `Wifi` the application work very well, but when I disconnect from `WiFi` and turn on `3G`, the mail can't be sent. It seems that I cant reach out to the mail server, even that the mailserver is public on the internet, not locally on the network.

Does the SMTP port changes when I connect to 3G? If so, this is very strange. The codesnippet for sending mail is beneath

```
package Logic;

public class SendMail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    public SendMail() {

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
        // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
                .getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);



    }

    public SendMail(Context c) {
        this();

        sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
        _host = sharedPrefs.getString("host", null);
        _port = sharedPrefs.getString("port", null);
        _sport = sharedPrefs.getString("port", null); 
        _user = sharedPrefs.getString("mail", null);
        _pass = sharedPrefs.getString("pw", null); 

    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
                && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                && !_body.equals("")) {

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new GMailAuthenticator(_user, _pass));

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);


            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email, henger noe her?!
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);


        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    class GMailAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        String user;
        String pw;

        public GMailAuthenticator(String username, String password) {
            super();
            this.user = username;
            this.pw = password;
        }

        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pw);
        }
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");

        return props;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        this._to = toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        this._from = string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
        this._subject = string;
    }
}
```

Yes, I have specified the correct permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any log trace that could give a hint on the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ISP restrict usage of SMTP servers and force you to use their SMTP servers instead of your own.
So you'd receive mail from `pop.yourmailserver.com` and send mail using `smtp.yourisp.com`.

Or, they forbid you to send mail using SMTP from 3G.